# How do I install LAMMPS and OVITO in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: software-installation

LAMMPS is a molecular dynamics simulation software. I downloaded the software but I am unable to install LAMMPS. I was searching for a file like `.exe` in Windows, but I can't find it.

Could you provide a step by step procedure to install this program on Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it well written in the [help pages of the software](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html#ubuntu)

> To install the appropriate personal-package archive (PPA), do the
>   following once:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gladky-anton/lammps
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> To install LAMMPS do the following once:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install lammps-daily
> ```
>
> This downloads an executable named "lammps-daily" to your box, which
>   can then be used in the usual way to run input scripts:
>
> ```
> lammps-daily < in.lj
> ```

If you have problems following this procedure to install, please write a comment here below.

Comment: Thanks i did it by hook or crook method through terminal commands copied from LAMMPS download page.